# How to make the top bars(title bars) of windows thinner in Ubuntu

Tags: gnome, wayland, dconf, borders

IMHO the top is too thick and useless. Ideally I like to find the setting either in dconf or edit the file that decided how thick the upper bar should  [image]

I installed [tweak](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-tweaks) but it was not there and I tried

I am currently using wayland but I am open to any other semi civil g manager

Answer (score 0):

credit goes to  at [hydrocat](https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/a7bvk8/how_to_make_gnome3_window_decoration_thinner/)
if file : ~/.config/gtk-4.0/gtk.css
simply put:

```
headerbar {
    margin: 0 1em 0 1em;
    padding: 0;
    border-width: 0px;
    font-size: 12pt;
    min-height: 0px;
}

headerbar * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    border-width: 0;
    min-height: 0px;
}

headerbar box {
    padding: 0.1em 0.5em 0.1em 0.5em;
}
```

You can add whatever else you like but this fixed my problem